# Setting the environment in Gemfile for bundling install/update based on a customize file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

hi, all
I build a sinatra app, the main files for bundling as the following,

environment.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sequel'

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'development'

configure :production do
     #do something
end

configure :development, :test do
     #do something
end
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sequel'

gem 'pg', :group => :production
gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]
```

So, how to let the bundle install based on the ENV['RACK_ENV'] in my environment.rb file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When doing a bundler require you can specify which groups to be required.

For example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'
  Bundler.require(:default, :development)
else
  Bundler.require(:default)
require 'sinatra'
```

More info on the bundler site gemfile specifications found [here](http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/gemfile.5.html).

Comment: Good, putting this code to my file environment.rb , it works.

Comment: You could also do: `Bundler.require(:default, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym)` and optionally add :development and :test namespaces.