# Why is 'coffee-rails' in the :assets group while 'jquery-rails' is in the :default group in a new Rails project's Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, asset-pipeline

If gems in the `:assets` group are not included in the production environment (as per [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351607/how-is-the-assets-group-in-rails-3-1-handled-by-bundler)), then why is `coffee-rails` in the `:assets` group by default? Where should I put my other `*-rails` gems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production coffeeScripts will be precompiled, so there is no necessity to include that gem for [production environment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production)

If you want to include gems for production, you should make another group

```
group:production do
    gem 'mysql'
    gem 'sinatra'
end
```

and let bundler to install this group as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7806673/1064025)

Comment: How about the jquery-rails (this is asked in title but not in body)